# How can I combine properties from different classes

Tags: c#, class, razor

Let's say I have two classes like

```
public partial class dbUserDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    //some properties
}
public partial class SomeOtherClass
{
    [DisplayName("Profile Picture (max. 2MB)")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    //some properties
}
```

And I want to combine some properties like

```
public class Settings
{
    //HttpPostedFileBase File
    //public string Bio { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@model myAppp.Models.Settings

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bio)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.File)
```

Is it possible to use in this way? I know something about `interface` and `partial`. But I dont know how i will exactly figure out.

Comment: are you familiar with how to make a `List<T>` of Class inside of the Settings Class..? here is a tutorial on [Nested Classes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20628/A-Tutorial-on-Nested-Classes-in-C)

Comment: _" I know something about interface"_ - you're on the right track.  Do some reading.  We don't do tutorials though.  Good luck!

Comment: @MethodMan do you mean this?         `public class Settings
        {
            public dbUserDetails _dbUserDetails { get; set; }
            public SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass { get; set; }
        }`

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you would have to pass the information from `dbUserDetails` and `SomeOtherClass` to you Settings class. The easiest way for this would be to simply create the `Settings` class with instances of the two other classes and make them available as properties:

```
public class Settings{

    private dbUserDetails userDetails;
    public dbUserDetails UserDetails {
        return userDetails;
    }

    private SomeOtherClass someOtherInfo;
    public SomeOtherClass SomeOtherInfo{
        return someOtherInfo;
    }

    public Settings(dbUserDetails user, SomeOtherInfo other)    {
        userDetails = user;
        someOtherInfo = other;
    }
}
```

Now you can access them this way: `m => m.UserDetails.Bio`

I did it via this way of accessing and not the way you mentioned before (direct access) because you would otherwise have the property duplicated at two positions. I would only do that if there was a good reason for this.

**Edit:**

For some clarification on why I chose the above written code:
Storing the `dbUserDetails` and `SomeOtherClass` objects in `Settings` does not create significant memory overhead at this point. All their properties should be accessible using `Settings` to they have to be stored somewhere. Therefore I decided to just leave them where they are.
A memory problem would only occur if the two classes stored more information than you want to make accessible and are not used anymore so that they could be deleted. In this case it would make sense to actually copy the information like this:

```
public class Settings{

    private string bio;
    public string Bio {
        return bio;
    }

    /*...*/

    public Settings(dbUserDetails user, SomeOtherInfo other)
    {
        bio = user.Bio;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

If you do not delete the two aforementioned objects when doing this, you store the information twice (=> memory overhead). This is worse than just storing references to the objects.

Another option would be this:

```
public class Settings{

    private dbUserDetails userDetails;

    public string Bio {
        return userDetails.Bio;
    }

    public Settings(dbUserDetails user, SomeOtherInfo other)
    {
        userDetails = user;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

This would be the same idea as the first one but with direct access to the properties. It would work as well but lead to more code duplication. Each new property in the sub objects would lead to a property in `Settings`

Comment: thank you for the reply @Nicholas. I know that I could do it this way, but I will access all the other properties from base classes (`dbUserDetails` and `SomeOtherClass`), right?

Comment: Yes. This will be the case if you access them via the base objects. If you do not want to do this you would have to duplicate the data. This means getting all the information from the two classes and store them again in separate variables of `Settings`. I would not recommend this as this results in more memory usage and duplication of information which can for example be problematic when updating information.

Comment: I really do not want to duplicate. I just wanted not to pass useless info from other objects for less memory usage and to be more safe.

Comment: I edited the answer. Does this clarify the situation?

Comment: Actually i was similarly trying to do that right now. In that way, will i have the same `attributes` with base class? (e.g.  `[AllowHtml]`)

Comment: If you access the properties via the base objects you will keep the attributes (as they are part of the class you then access). If you copy the properties you also need to copy the attributes as they are part of the property declaration and not of the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103149/discussion-between-pcodea-xonos-and-nicholas-schuster).